# Using date variable in a step function AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-step-functions

I created a step function for creating EMR cluster
I want that the date in the steps to change according to the date I execute my step function.
(if I run it today - 13.6.2023, I want it to run day before 12.6.2023) how can I do it?
This is my code:

```
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "EMR CreateCluster",
  "States": {
    "EMR CreateCluster": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:createCluster.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "Name": "IOretrieve",
        "ServiceRole": "EMR_DefaultRole",
        "JobFlowRole": "EMR_EC2_DefaultRole",
        "ReleaseLabel": "emr-6.8.0",
        "Applications": [
          {
            "Name": "Spark"
          }
        ],
        "LogUri": "s3://",
        "VisibleToAllUsers": true,
        "Instances": {
          "Ec2SubnetId": "subnet",
          "Ec2KeyName": "",
          "EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup": "",
           "EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup": "",
          "KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps": true,
          "InstanceFleets": [
            {
              "InstanceFleetType": "MASTER",
              "Name": "Master",
              "TargetOnDemandCapacity": 1,
              "InstanceTypeConfigs": [
                {
                  "InstanceType": "m5.xlarge"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "InstanceFleetType": "CORE",
              "Name": "CORE",
              "TargetOnDemandCapacity": 5,
              "InstanceTypeConfigs": [
                {
                  "InstanceType": "r5.2xlarge"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "BootstrapActions": [
            {
              "Name": "Custom action",
              "ScriptBootstrapAction": {
                "Path": "s3://",
                "Args": []
              }
            }
          ],
        "Configurations": [
            {
                "Classification": "core-site",
                "Properties": {
                    "fs.s3a.connection.maximum": "1000"
                }
            },
            {
                "Classification": "spark",
                "Properties": {
                    "maximizeResourceAllocation": "true"
                }
            }
        ]
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.cluster",
      "Next": "Run first step"
    },
    "Run first step": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:addStep.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "ClusterId.$": "$.cluster.ClusterId",
        "Step": {
          "Name": "My first EMR step",
          "HadoopJarStep": {
            "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
            "Args": [
              "spark-submit",
              "--deploy-mode",
              "client",
              "s3://",
              "--local_run",
              "False",
              "--date_path",
              "year=2023/month=06/day=12/"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.firstStep",
      "Next": "Run second step"
    },
    "Run second step": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:addStep.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "ClusterId.$": "$.cluster.ClusterId",
        "Step": {
          "Name": "My second EMR step",
          "HadoopJarStep": {
            "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
            "Args": [
              "spark-submit",
              "--deploy-mode",
              "client",
              "s3://",
              "--local_run",
              "False",
              "--date_path",
              "year=2023/month=06/day=12/"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.secondStep",
      "Next": "EMR TerminateCluster"
    },
    "EMR TerminateCluster": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:terminateCluster",
      "Parameters": {
        "ClusterId.$": "$.cluster.ClusterId"
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

The date path is what I want to change:
"--date_path",
"year=2023/month=06/day=12/"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**AWS Step Functions** provides some simple **[Intrinsic Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html)** for math operations, like `States.MathRandom` and `States.MathAdd`.

However, at the time of writing (June 2023), more complex calculations, like getting the date of the previous day can't be done out-of-the-box and require invoking an external process, i.e. a [Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-lambda.html).

---

Having that said, you can retrieve and format the current date and time following the steps below.

**Step 1:**

Retrieve the execution time of the specific step from the **[Context Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html)** using

```
$$.State.EnteredTime
```

This will return the date and time using the following format:

```
2019-03-26T20:14:13.192Z
```

**Step 2:**

Split the execution time into an array using `States.StringSplit`:

```
States.StringSplit($$.State.EnteredTime, '-,T')
```

This will return the following Array:

```
[
  "2019",
  "03",
  "26",
  "20:14:13.192Z"
]`
```

**Step 3:**

Format the date path string using `States.Format` with the first three elements of the array:

```
States.Format('year={}/month={}/day={}', States.ArrayGetItem($.date.splitDate, 0), States.ArrayGetItem($.date.splitDate, 1), States.ArrayGetItem($.date.splitDate, 2))
```

**Step 4:**

Create the Args array using `States.Array`:

```
States.Array('spark-submit', '--deploy-mode', 'client', 's3://', '--local_run', 'False', '--date_path',$.datePath)
```

---

To show you how this works in the context of your state machine, I've 1/ added an additional pass state called `"Format date path": {...}` to your state machine, and replaced the `HadoopJarStep.Args` attribute in your task state (`"Run second step": {...}`):

```
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "EMR CreateCluster",
  "States": {
    "EMR CreateCluster": {
      ...,
      "Next": "Format date path"
    },
    "Format date path": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "datePath.$": "States.Format('year={}/month={}/day={}', States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit($$.State.EnteredTime, '-,T'), 0), States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit($$.State.EnteredTime, '-,T'), 1), States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit($$.State.EnteredTime, '-,T'), 2))"
      },
      "Next": "Run second step"
    },
    "Run second step": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:addStep.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "ClusterId.$": "$.cluster.ClusterId",
        "Step": {
          "Name": "My second EMR step",
          "ClusterId.$": "$.cluster.ClusterId",
          "HadoopJarStep": {
            "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
            "Args.$": "States.Array('spark-submit', '--deploy-mode', 'client', 's3://', '--local_run', 'False', '--date_path',$.datePath)"
          }
        }
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.secondStep",
      "Next": "EMR TerminateCluster"
    },
    "EMR TerminateCluster": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```